# Can I create BASH function that will hold text block that can then be called for output to FILE and SCREEN to cut down on code block repetition

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a BASH utility that outputs measurements to screen live as it runs and writes the result to file at the same time.
I am having to repeat the same code twice (see below).

Once to write to screen, and

Once to write to file.

This seems like a lot of redundancy to me.

Can I put one text block into something like a function then call it to be written to screen and file at the same time?

This would cut down on a lot of re-keying.

Example below

```
###### write out to file : push end time at end ################
echo >> $file_name
echo "End time: "$end_time >> $file_name
echo >> $file_name
echo >> $file_name
echo >> $file_name

######  print to screen : push end time at end  #################

echo 
echo "End time: "$end_time 
echo
echo
echo
```

So I'd be looking for someting like this

```
funtion text_block{
######  print to screen : push end time at end  #################
echo 
echo "End time: "$end_time 
echo
echo
echo
}
```

Then a command that does something like this

`"command` print `text_block` to screen, print `text_block` to file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the utility `tee`

```
command | tee my_file.out
```

this will both write a file name my_file.out and write it to stdout.

Source this post from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418899/1195001)

Comment: that really helped me clean up  repeat code and get rid of typos introduced by unnecessary re-keying when making changes. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome @Kes